# Configure Jedis timeout

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I'm having problems completing an `.hgetall()`, here's what I've tried:

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis(REDIS_MASTER_NODE);
jedis.connect();
jedis.configSet("timeout", "30");

Map<String, String> alreadyStored = jedis.hgetAll(redisTargetHash);
```

and here's what I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:79)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:131)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:199)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.hgetAll(Jedis.java:851)
```

This solved the issue:

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis(REDIS_MASTER_NODE, 6379, 1800);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If what you want to do is set Jedis connection `timeout`, you should do it using the special constructor made for that:

```
public Jedis(final String host, final int port, final int timeout)
```

What you are doing is setting the *timeout* on Redis settings from `Jedis`. Doing `CONFIG SET timeout 60`, means that Redis will close *idle* client connections after `60` seconds. That's why you get the exception in Jedis.

Comment: Whats the unit of timeout? As in, is it in seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: @xetorthio can you tell me how I can specify query timeout in jedis ? Currently I am using `jedis-2.6.0.jar` Please also tell me what are default values of them.
As per my understanding `connectionTimeout` is new connection establishing timeout.

Comment: The timeout parameter of the constructor is in milliseconds because this value is affected internally to java.net.Socket#connect(java.net.SocketAddress, int) and java.net.Socket#setSoTimeout(int) methods. So this this value is connection and a socket read timeout.

Answer (score 13):

This is a bit of an extension to xetorthio's answer, but here is similar approach for use with a JedisPool.  (Caveat: this is based on my understanding from looking at the Jedis version 2.6.2 code directly and has not been tested in a live use case.)

```
    JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
    jedisPoolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(writeTimeout);
    JedisPool pool = new JedisPool(jedisPoolConfig, redisHost, port, readTimeout);
```

The writeTimeout is max time for a Jedis resource from the pool to wait for a write operation.

The readTimeout specified for the pool constructor is the wait time for a socket read, see `java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout` for more specific details.

Comment: JedisPoolConfig inherits maxWaitMillis from BaseGenericObjectPool , its just a timeout for getting/borrowing the object from JedisPoolConfig

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/BaseGenericObjectPool.html#getMaxWaitMillis--

I dont think it has anything to do with writetimeout of remote redis

Comment: maxWaitMillis -: The maximum wait time (in milliseconds) of the caller when the connection pool resource is exhausted.

Answer (score 4):

Few things to consider:

1. For both Jedis and JedisPool classes, timeout is in miliseconds.
   Default timeout, at least in 2.5.1, as I see, is 2000 (milisec): `int redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 2000 [0x7d0]`
2. As per [this](http://redis.io/topics/clients) documentation, Redis 2.6 or higher does not close connection, even if the client is idle. I have not verified this yet, and I will try to update the post when I do.

Comment: did you get a chance to see if the connection is closed after the idle period timeout? Also, I guess you're saying Jedis (not Redis) doesn't close.

Comment: It is Redis 2.6 and higher that will leave client connections open by default.