# Broken pipe while using Jedis Pool

Tags: java, redis, pool, jedis

I'm using Jedis to perform a lot of insertions/reads in Redis. 
The Redis server is using the default configuration.
The problem appears when I start using a few threads and the exception is:

*redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Pipe quebrado (Write failed)*

I've searched a lot about this problem but couldn't find the reason of it or it's solve. The code I'm using to perform these tests is below:

```
public class RedisFacade {

private static RedisFacade instancia = null;
// Initialize the Connection
final JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = buildPoolConfig();
JedisPool pool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, "localhost");
Jedis jedis;
int i = 0;

private RedisFacade() {
}

public static RedisFacade getInstancia() {
    if (instancia == null) {
        instancia = new RedisFacade();
    }
    return instancia;
}

// retorna um cliente jedis da pool
public Jedis getDB() {
    if (jedis == null) {
        jedis = pool.getResource();
    }
    return jedis;
}

//inserting
public void insert(Document d) {
    String key = i + d.getString("date") + d.getString("time");
    String value = d.toString();
    this.getDB().set(key, value);
    i++;
}

//reading
public void read(String date, String time) {
    Object doc = this.getDB().get(i + date + time);
    i++;
    System.out.println(doc);
}

public void destroyPool() {
    this.pool.destroy();
}

private JedisPoolConfig buildPoolConfig() {
    final JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
    poolConfig.setMaxTotal(1100);
    poolConfig.setMaxIdle(16);
    poolConfig.setMinIdle(16);
    poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    poolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);
    poolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(true);poolConfig.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(Duration.ofSeconds(60).toMillis());
    poolConfig.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(Duration.ofSeconds(30).toMillis());
    poolConfig.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(3);
    poolConfig.setBlockWhenExhausted(true);
    return poolConfig;
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying to implement new constructors, new configurations for the pool and clients, I tried a simple way to fix the problem: close the resources I was getting from the pool. To do so, I've changed the following code:

```
public Jedis getDB() {
    jedis = pool.getResource();
    return jedis;
}

//cria um _id pra ser usado novamente quando for buscar os documentos
public void insert(Document d) {
    String key = "key" + i;
    String value = d.toString();
    Jedis jedis = this.getDB();
    jedis.set(key, value);
    jedis.close();
    i++;
}

//busca pelo _id
public void read() {
    Jedis jedis = this.getDB();
    Object doc = jedis.get("key" + i);
    jedis.close();
    i++;
    System.out.println(doc);
}
```

After changing the code, the service started to work I was planning, so I'll accept this as a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like it's a timeout issue.

See this thread: [Configure Jedis timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993644/configure-jedis-timeout)

And also this discussion: https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/185

So I would try instantiating `JedisPool` with a timeout parameter
(i.e. https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/JedisPool.java#L201, but there are many other constructors)

and setting `CONFIG SET timeout 600` in redis (with a 10 minute timeout for instance).

#### Edit

The `JedisPool` timeout is in milliseconds it seems.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! I tried all of your tips, but couldn't solve the problem... But then I tried to close the resources I was getting from the pool and it worked.